# A more optimized or effective way to handle this PHP conditions

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, optimization, syntax

I'm looking for a more elegant or efficient way to handle this if-statements. I'm kinda new to PHP and while the script below works, it looks kinda strange to me and I'm pretty sure there is a better way (performance and/or structure wise) to handle a case like this.

I have an array **$atts** and there can be two values in it: 
**border-top** and **border-bottom**

These come from two checkboxes you can select, so there are 4 combinations. Either one, both, or none.

My code:

```
// First check
$border = '';
if ( ! empty( $atts['border']['border-top'] ) ) {
    $border_top = $atts['border']['border-top'];
}
if ( ! empty( $atts['border']['border-bottom'] ) ) {
    $border_bottom = $atts['border']['border-bottom'];
}

// Create the class
if ( ! empty( $border_top) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $border_bottom) ) {
        $border = 'border-top-and-bottom';
    } else {
        $border = 'border-top';
    }
} else {
    $border = 'border-bottom';
}

// Add class to the main array
if ( ! empty( $border ) ) { $attributes['class']['border'] = $border; }
```

Why I did it like this:

**First check:** The first two if-statements are there to check if they are set at all, since these are no booleans. If I don't select a checkbox there is no 0 value but instead doesn't create a value in **$atts**. Without the first two if-statements I would receive an PHP error.

**Create the class:** Here I try to see what combination was set. Either top and bottom, just one of those two or none. Especially this part of the code can be put in a better more elegant way, I think.

**Add the class:** Here I add the result of the part before as a new entry to the final array, or not if none of the checkboxes was selected.

I mean, so far it seems to work like it was intended.. I'm just curious if there is a better and shorter way to solve this case then all these if-statements.

edit:

Ok, looking at it outside the editor I noticed that was pretty dumb, since the first and middle part were kinda doing the same thing. I already narrowed it down:

```
$border = '';
if ( ! empty( $atts['border']['border-top'] ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $atts['border']['border-bottom'] ) ) {
        $border = 'border-top-and-bottom';
    } else {
        $border = 'border-top';
    }
} elseif ( ! empty( $atts['border']['border-bottom'] ) ) {
    $border = 'border-bottom';
}
if ( ! empty( $border ) ) { $attributes['class']['border'] = $border; }
```

Comment: When niether `$atts['border']['border-top']` nor `$atts['border']['border-bottom']` is set the `$border` still will be evaluated to `'border-bottom'`. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: oops. you are right. I made the last else an elseif instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP's ternary operator : 
This line will reduce your variable name in program :

```
$array = $atts['border'];
```

After will test the value of border-top, this line means : 
"If $array['border-top'] is not empty, $top value will be 'border-top', else $top value will be null "

```
$top = (!empty($array['border-top'])) ? 'border-top' : '';
```

The same line for the border-bottom value :

```
$bottom = (!empty($array['border-bottom'])) ? 'border-bottom' : '';
```

Then we mix the var, this line means : 
"If $top and $bottom are not empty, $border value will be $top + '-and-bottom', else, $border value will be $top + $bottom (One is empty)"

`$border = (!empty($top) && !empty($bottom)) ? $top.'-and-bottom' : $top.$bottom`;

Then we just set the var :

```
$attributes['class']['border'] = (!empty($border)) ? $border : '';
echo $attributes['class']['border'];
```

Final :

```
$array = $atts['border'];
$top = (!empty($array['border-top'])) ? 'border-top' : '';
$bottom = (!empty($array['border-bottom'])) ? 'border-bottom' : '';
$border = (!empty($top) && !empty($bottom)) ? $top.'-and-bottom' : $top.$bottom;
$attributes['class']['border'] = (!empty($border)) ? $border : '';
echo $attributes['class']['border'];
```

Comment: thanks! that seems like a good way to do it. I rewrote it now and use the ternary operator.